# C program: Strcmp

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am new to C programming. I am trying to compare a two strings. I get the error: Multiple markers at this line. passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast. passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast

```
char names[SIZE][LENGTH];   
char srch_name[LENGTH];

if(strcmp(names[g][LENGTH], srch_name[LENGTH]) == 1)
```

Comment: `if(strcmp(names[g], srch_name) == 1)` will eliminate the warning, but note that if strings are equal, the return value is 0.

Comment: Both of the arguments you're passing to `strcmp` are `char` elements from arrays.  They have an integer type.  The arguments should have type `char *`.  Further, you are using `LENGTH` as an index into these arrays, which is out of bounds.  You really need to read a tutorial on C arrays and pointers before trying to code them.  The trial-and-error approach simply will not work.

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem is that you are passing a pair of `char`s to `strcmp`, rather than `char*`. This is easy to fix - this call will compile:

```
strcmp(names[g], srch_name)
```

A second problem, however, is that you do not check `strcmp` for a specific value, except zero: it returns a value less than zero, zero, or a number greater than zero depending on the comparison result.

- `<0` when the first character that does not match has a lower value in `ptr1` than in `ptr2`
- `0` when the contents of both strings are equal,
- `>0` when the first character that does not match has a greater value in `ptr1` than in `ptr2`

**Note:** Since C indexes arrays 0..LENGTH-1, dereferencing an array at its actual length as in `srch_name[LENGTH]` is almost always an error. The only situation when it is not an error is when you take the address of one-past-end element.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp()`'s prototype is

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

but both the parameters you gave are of type `char` and not `char *`.

Perhaps you meant

```
if(strcmp(names[g], srch_name) == 1)
```

And if you are checking if the strings are equal, note that `strcmp()` returns `0` if both strings have the same content.

Answer (score 1):

```
char names[SIZE][LENGTH];
```

`names` is an array of arrays of characters (`char **`).

Looking up an item in that array:

```
names[g]
```

is therefore an array of characters (`char *`). Looking up an item in that:

```
names[g][LENGTH]
```

gets you a character (`char`). And one that's out of bounds of the array at that, since the array's valid indexes only go from `0` to `LENGTH - 1`. `strcmp` needs you to pass an array of characters (`char *`), not a single character (`char`).

Solution: Get rid of the second lookup.

(also, the result of `strcmp` needs to be compared to `0`, not `1`)